# Laravel can not import class from correct file, it looks in controllers

Tags: php, laravel, helper

I tried to separate additional classes into files gathered in the `App\Core` directory. I have already tried different solutions for the problem and nothing has worked for me. I managed to create one test class static `SearchProcess` placed in the `SearchProcess.php` file. So the full path looks like `App\Core\SearchProcess.php`.

The file contains:

```
<?php

namespace App\Core;


class SearchProcess
{
    public static function method_1(string $arg)
    {
        //Does things...
    }

    public static function method_2(string $arg)
    {
        //Does different things...
    }
}
```

The file is 'registered' in the `config\app.php` in the section `aliases`:

```
    'aliases' => [
        //Custom aliases...
        'SearchProcess' => App\Core\SearchProcess::class,
    ],
```

Finally I import it as:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

// use SearchProcess;
use App\Core;

class SearchController extends Controller
{

    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        //Does before staf...
        $search_value = SearchProcess::method_1($search_value_raw);

        //Does after staf...
    }

}
```

I run `composer dump-autoload` afterwards, but it does not change anything.
I get an error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\SearchProcess' not found
```

Moreover I do not know why it looks for the file in the controllers directory?

Comment: You need to change this : `use App\Core\SearchProcess` in order to use it

Comment: Ok, that have solved the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// use SearchProcess;
use App\Core\SearchProcess;
```